# get term objects and post objects in query

Tags: wp-query, filters, terms

I'm trying til change the search results of the add link tinymce popup box to include some terms from custom taxonomies. I'm using the `wp_link_query_args` and `wp_link_query` filters.

My issue is that the query from `wp_link_query_args` is using the standard `WP_query` class to fetch the results.

I have searched everywhere for a solution but i can't seem to find anyway to include terms as object in a `WP_query`. Is this possible at all?

For clarification i'm not trying to get `posts` of certain `terms`. I'm trying to all posts AND the term objects.

For the code:

The `WP_query` arguments I'm hooking into is:

```
$pts = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );
$pt_names = array_keys( $pts );

$query = array(
    'post_type' => $pt_names,
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
);

// THIS IS THE FILTER I'M HOOKING INTO
$query = apply_filters( 'wp_link_query_args', $query );
// AFTER THIS LINE I DON'T HAVE CONTROL OF CODE
// Do main query.
$get_posts = new WP_Query;
$posts = $get_posts->query( $query );
```

Comment: You can't get terms from a `WP_Query`. You need a `WP_Term_Query` for that. There is a `wp_link_query` filter where you can filter the results list though, and you could hook into that, perform a WP_Term_Query, and append the results. Problem is that the editor expects post objects back, and WP_Term objects are different. You'd need to create fake WP_Post objects out of WP_Term objects before adding to the results. Then they'd show up as posts in the editor anyway, which could be confusing. I'm not sure there's a very easy way to go about this.

Comment: I tried filtering the results to include all the terms I needed. Problem is they break the ajax load and seem to ignore search patterns in all ways. Despite having added all of them with the same 4 arguments as the post has. I believe it was id, title, permalink and type. I guess my client will have to manually copy/paste the term archive link.

Thanks for the anwers anyways.